# Connect multiple socket-client from different servers on single web-browser page

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io, em-websocket-client

I have multiple servers in node js so each server has a socket client to communicate with the main server. when I connect all socket-client to the main server web page then I send a message to one specific client which I select but the message is sent to all connected clients so how to communicate with specific only one client

Comment: so your question is just how to send a message to a specific client?

Comment: On one page many socket-client connected so I want to send messages to specific client

Comment: how are you currently sending the message?

Comment: let host = 'http://' + server.ip_address + ':' + server.port_number;
     socket = io(host, {
         transports: ['websocket']
     });
     var form = document.getElementById('commandForm');
     var input = document.getElementById('serverCommand');
     form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

         e.preventDefault();
         if (input.value) {
             socket.emit('send command', input.value);
             input.value = '';
         }
     });
     socket.on('send command', function (msg, data) {
    let item= msg + data;
     })